# Is there a way to have a won opportunity be shared by two owners for commission purposes?

Tags: opportunity-split

Most of our sales have a simple commission structure, with the Account Executive (Opportunity Owner) getting their contracted % of the sale and if a junior team member set up the demo for them they are tagged in a custom User Lookup field on the opportunity for their %.  But sometimes we have special cases where we want two AE's to share credit for a sale (both on their paycheck and towards their monthly sales target).

Is there a way (without installing apps or 3rd-party systems) to cleanly reflect this at the Opportunity level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after a feature called Opportunity Splits: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=teamselling_opp_splits_overview.htm&language=en_US

Although it doesn't allow for duel ownership it does allow you to split the kudos among many people based on percentages or any currency field

If you want a brief look, Salesforce recently did some upgrades to this feature so there's some good videos in the release training area: http://www.salesforce.com/customer-resources/releases/summer14/release-training.jsp

Check out the Sales Cloud vid.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for posting a question after insufficient googling :-/

Comment: No worries dude!